# Evolutionary algorithm to optimize the range of a glider

Tags: python, performance, physics, genetic-algorithm

I created an evolutionary algorithm that optimises the range of a "glider"...ignore the accuracy of the physics behind the problem!

Any comments on how to improve the algorithm/my coding style would be greatly appreciated.

If it helps, here is the link to the [github repository.](https://github.com/peajayni/aeroplane_evolutionary_algorithm)

```
from __future__ import division

import random
import math
import bitstring

POPULATION_SIZE = 8
N_ITER = 2000

#Parameters used to evaluate the aircraft performance
V = 10
RHO = 1.2
HEIGHT = 100


class Param:

    def __init__(self, min_val, max_val, value = None):
        """
        Attributes and methods associated with an aeroplane parameter which is to
        be optimised

        Inputs:
            min_val:    Minimum allowed value for the paramter
            max_val:    Maximum allowed value for the paramter
            value:      If provided, the inital value of the paramter
                        If not provided, a random value is generated

        The range between the min_val and max_val will be split into 255 "steps" to 
        allow the value to be encoded using 8 bits. 
        """

        self.min_val = min_val
        self.max_val = max_val

        self.step_size = (self.max_val - self.min_val) / 255

        #if a value is provided, round it to an allowed value
        if value:
            self.step = value // self.step_size
            self.val =   self.step * self.step_size

        #generate a random value
        else:
            self.val = value
            self.generate_value()

    def generate_value(self):
        """
        Generates a random starting value
        """
        self.step = random.randint(0, 255)

        #randomly generate a value within the allowed range
        self.val = self.min_val + self.step * self.step_size

    def update(self, step):
        """
        Updates the parameter value based on the "step" paramter, which will be in
        the range 0 -> 255
        """

        self.val = self.min_val + step * self.step_size


class Plane:
    def __init__(self, span=None, chord=None, angle=None, genes = None):
        """
        Attributes and methods associated with an aeroplane

        Inputs:
            span:   wing span
            chord:  wing chord
            angle:  wing installation angle
            genes:  genes for the aeroplane

            These parameters are randomly generated if not provided
        """

        #min value = 5, max value = 10
        self.span = Param(5, 10, span)

        #min value = 0.5, max value = 1
        self.chord = Param(0.5, 1, chord)

        #min angle = 1, max value = 45 ...note: units = degrees
        self.angle = Param(1, 45, angle)

        #aeroplane glide range
        self.range = 0

        #if a string of genes is provided, use this to override any random values
        if genes:
            self.genes = genes

            self.update_values()

        #else use the values to generate a gene sequence
        else:
            self.genes = None

            self.update_genes()

    def update_genes(self):
        """
        Maps the aircraft parameters to a 24 bit gene sequence
        """

        genes = ""

        genes += bitstring.BitArray(uint=self.span.step, length=8).bin[2:]  
        genes += bitstring.BitArray(uint=self.chord.step, length=8).bin[2:]     
        genes += bitstring.BitArray(uint=self.angle.step, length=8).bin[2:]     

        self.genes = genes

        #evaluate the design
        self.evaluate()

    def evaluate(self):
        """
        Calculates the glide range of the aircraft

        Excuse the very simple and inaccurate maths...
        """

        #lift coefficient
        CL = 2 * math.pi * self.angle.val * math.pi / 180

        #Wing area
        s = self.span.val * self.chord.val

        #Aspect ratio
        AR = self.span.val / self.chord.val

        #lift
        L = 0.5 * RHO * V**2 * s * CL

        #Drag Coefficient
        CD = 0.01 +  CL**2 / (math.pi * AR)

        #Drag
        D = 0.5 * RHO * V**2 * s * CD

        #Lift over drag
        LD = L / D

        #Range
        self.range = LD * HEIGHT


    def update_values(self):
        """
        Converts a gene sequence into parameter values
        """

        #get the step values for the parameters
        span_step = bitstring.BitArray(bin=self.genes[:8]).uint
        chord_step = bitstring.BitArray(bin=self.genes[8:16]).uint
        angle_step = bitstring.BitArray(bin=self.genes[16:]).uint

        #update the values
        self.span.update(span_step)
        self.chord.update(chord_step)
        self.angle.update(angle_step)

        #calculate the range
        self.evaluate()

    def mutate(self):
        """
        Creates a mutation by flipping a bit at a random location in the gene sequence
        """

        loc = random.randint(0, 23)

        if self.genes[loc] == "1":

            self.genes = self.genes[:loc] + "0" + self.genes[loc+1:]
        else:
            self.genes = self.genes[:loc] + "1" + self.genes[loc+1:]

        #update the values (this will also recalculate the range)
        self.update_values()


class GA:
    def __init__(self):
        """
        Attributes and methods associated with the actual genetic algorithm
        """

        #list to store the population of aeroplanes

        self.population = []

        #actually create the aeroplanes
        for i in range(POPULATION_SIZE):

            self.population.append(Plane())

        #sort the aeroplanes by range, the best being at the end of the list
        self.population.sort(key= lambda plane: plane.range)

        #used to count the number of iterations
        self.counter = 0

    def show(self):
        """
        Prints out the details of the population
        """

        for i in range(POPULATION_SIZE):
            print("{:4d}: span = {:7.4f}, chord = {:7.4f}, angle = {:7.4f}, glide range = {:5.0f}, genes = {}".format(
                self.counter, 
                self.population[i].span.val, 
                self.population[i].chord.val, 
                self.population[i].angle.val, 
                self.population[i].range, 
                self.population[i].genes
                ))


    def random_parent(self):
        """
        Selects a random parent from the population, using a uniform product distribution
        """

        index = random.random() * random.random() * (POPULATION_SIZE - 1)
        index = int(index)

        return self.population[index]

    def mate(self, mum, dad, mutation_rate = 0.1):
        """
        Creates two "child" aeroplanes by combining the gene sequence of the two parents.
        Mutations of the children is also possible

        Inputs:
            mum:            Plane object to be used as one of the parents
            dad:            Plane object to be used as one of the parents
            mutation_rate:  chance of a mutation occuring
        """

        #list to store the location of 3 random cuts
        loc = []

        #add random cuts
        for i in range(3):
            loc.append(random.randint(0, 23))

        #sort the cuts for correct indexing
        loc.sort()

        #create the children's gene sequences
        child_genes1 = mum.genes[0:loc[0]] + dad.genes[loc[0]:loc[1]] + mum.genes[loc[1]:loc[2]] + dad.genes[loc[2]:]
        child_genes2 = dad.genes[0:loc[0]] + mum.genes[loc[0]:loc[1]] + dad.genes[loc[1]:loc[2]] + mum.genes[loc[2]:]

        #actually create the children Plane objects 
        child1 = Plane(genes = child_genes1)
        child2 = Plane(genes = child_genes2)


        #allow for a mutation in each child
        if random.random() <= mutation_rate:
            child1.mutate()

        if random.random() <= mutation_rate:
            child2.mutate()

        return [child1, child2]

    def create_children(self):
        """
        Creates children which will hopefully replace the worst performing designs
        """


        for i in range(int(POPULATION_SIZE/2)):
            mum = self.random_parent()
            dad = self.random_parent()

            children = self.mate(mum, dad)

            #check if a child is better than the worst design in the population
            for child in children:
                if child.range >= self.population[0].range:

                    #if so, kill the worst design and add the child to the population
                    self.population.pop(0)
                    self.population.append(child)

                    #resort the population
                    self.population.sort(key = lambda plane: plane.range)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    ga = GA()
    ga.show()

    for i in range(N_ITER):

        ga.create_children()
        ga.counter += 1
        ga.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overall your code is nicely formulated, well spaced and easy to read, even though I'm not into genetic algorithms. Your coding style seems pretty consistent, and that is always good.

I have the following comments to your code:

- *Consider using one-line docstrings* – It is a little spacious to use three (or four) lines for one-line docstrings. So I would consider, for some of your cases to do like this:

  ```
  def show(self):
      """Prints out the details of the population."""

      for i in range(POPULATION_SIZE):
      ...
  ```

  But this is matter of preferences, and you do deserve credit for being consistent. Still I think you have consistency, and have one-line docstrings here and there
- *Unclear names on `update_values()` and `update_genes()`* – The names here doesn't correspond with what the methods actually do. If I understand them correctly, the `update_genes()` transforms the variables into `self.genes`, whilst the the `update_values()` the genes to the variables. I would try to find some more describing names here.
- *Describe what `self.genes` is, and how it is meant to work* – A good description here could be in place, and help understanding of the general code, and the following algorithm.
- *Use better names in `evaluate()`* – I think you would benefit from typing out the variable names, and then removing comments in `evaluate()`. In most of the formulas you only use one or two of the preceding calculate formulas, so there should plenty of space within the 80 character line length limit to use longer more descriptive names like in this code segment:

  ```
  def evaluate(self):
       """Calculates the glide range of the aircraft."""

       lift_coefficient = 2 * math.pi * self.angle.val * math.pi / 180

       wing_area = self.span.val * self.chord.val

       aspect_ratio = self.span.val / self.chord.val

       lift = 0.5 * RHO * V**2 * wing_area * lift_coefficient

       drag_coefficient = 0.01 +  lift_coefficient**2 / (math.pi * aspect_ratio)

       drag = 0.5 * RHO * V**2 * wing_area * drag_coefficient

       lift_over_drag = lift / drag

       self.range = lift_over_drag * HEIGHT
  ```

  It is still a heavy formula block, but it makes a little more sense, I think.
- *Move the `self.genes` above `else:` up one line* – Kind of strange to have it so strongly connected to the `else:`
- *Rename `GA` to `GeneticAlgorithm`* – Or something more meaningful than just `GA`...
- *Take it all the way, introducing `son` and `daughter`* – I recently discovered that I really don't like variables named with numbers, like `child1`and `child2`, so I suggest taking it all the way and call them `son` and `daughter`.
- *Describe the general principle of the `GeneticAlgorithm` class* – Whilst the `Plane` class is kind of self describing, the `GeneticAlgorithm` class could benefit from some more explanations.
- *Use `for _ in range(...)` when you don't care about the iterate value* – In the `main` code block, and in `create_children()` you don't seem to care about what the actual value of `i` is, and then you could use the special variable name of `_` to clearly show that you are not intending to use this variable, but you need the `for` loop to build your loop.

So all in all, keep up the good work, and happy coding!